# How to convert mouse position into css 3d transformed element position

Tags: html, svg, 3d, transform, cursor-position

As shown in JSFiddle, when you move the mouse over the 3d transformed div, I tried to convert the mouse position into the css 3d transformed element space.

Which means, the red spot should always be display at the exact position of the mouse.

However, the DIV html element doesn't have method getScreenCTM or getTransformToElement or matrixTransform which can be used to transform the point.  Does anybody know how to achieve that?

http://jsfiddle.net/9cv2y0dp/

```
var tel = $('#transformed')[0];
var box = $('#box')[0];
tel.style.transform 
    = 'translate3d(100px,100px,0px) rotateY(45deg)';
var rect = tel.getBoundingClientRect();
$('#transformed').bind('mousedown', function(e){
    var evt = e || event;
    var x = evt.clientX;
    var y = evt.clientY;
    $('#cursor')[0].style.left = (x - rect.left) + 'px';
    $('#cursor')[0].style.top = (y - rect.top) + 'px';
    box.innerHTML = (x - rect.left) + 'px<br/>' + (y - rect.top) + 'px';
});
```

Comment: Worth being aware the 3d transform in that doesn't work for me in Safari 8, it does in Chrome.

Comment: Unfortunately, the [CSS transforms spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transforms/) does not yet include any equivalents to the SVG dom methods for manipulating transformations.  You would need to calculate the matrices yourself.  The math is in the spec, it really depends on how comfortable you are with matrix algebra.